# React.createRef() not works

Tags: reactjs

I create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk052zjmyp) to test-out new react createRef api but ie seams something is wrong.
I followed [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but I couldn't figure out what's wrong.
can anybody take a look at code please.

> "react": "16.5.2",
>
> "react-dom": "16.5.2",

Parent Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    const node = this.myRef.current;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComponent ref={this.myRef} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(node);
          }}
        >
          Run Me
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Child Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    message: "nothing!"
  };
  SayHi = () => {
    this.setState({ message: "Hi From Parent" });
  };
  render() {
    const { message } = this.state;
    return <div>Message: {message}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.myRef.current` expected to return? And what does the log output?

Comment: it returns null, but I am expecting ref object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to your ref not being fully initialised after the first render, meaning that when `onClick` is invoked, your're technically "logging" an cached copy of an uninitialised value.

Consider making the following change to cause the initialised and "current" `ref` to be accessed during the `onClick` event:

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    // const node = this.myRef.current; <-- Remove this
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComponent ref={this.myRef} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            // Move to here, causes the current ref to be accessed during onClick
            const node = this.myRef.current;
            console.log(node);
          }}
        >
          Run Me
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What should I do if I want to use the ref in other parts of my code? for example in another method of class? seams in all other places is null !

Comment: Hi @SaeidOstad, it should be possible for you to access the ref from other methods in your component in the same way - do you have some source code on github that I can look at to help you more?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to run SayHi() method of child component upon clicking of button, In your parent component's render you need to remove `const node = this.myRef.current` and the `onClick` method will be as follows

`onClick={() => {
            this.myRef.current.SayHi();
          }}`

this will invoke SayHi() method of child component.